# Maximizing/optimizing a function with constraints in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe, optimization

Suppose I have this dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)
a <- seq(from=-0.5, to=0.5, by=.01)
success_rate <- sample(a, size=945, replace=TRUE)
attempts <- sample(1:800, 945, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(success_rate,attempts)
```

I want to find X1 and X2 that maximize the following function:

```
{X1*df$attempts[1] + X2*df$success_rate[1]}/{X1*max(df$attempts) + X2*max(df$success_rate)}
```

However, the maximization should be done under these constraints:

The result of the function must be <=1 for all observations within the dataframe ,X1 + X2 = 1 and X1 and X2 should not be equal to 0.

I used lpsolve to solve it but it always gives me 1 and 0 as solutions even though I specify Xs cannot be equal to 0. Here is what I have:

```
df$success_rate <- (df$success_rate-min(df$success_rate))/(max(df$success_rate)-min(df$success_rate))
df$attempts <- (df$attempts-min(df$attempts))/(max(df$attempts)-min(df$attempts))

aux <- cbind(inputs, outputs)
f.obj <- c(df2$pass_snapsscale[2], df2$pass_perscale[2])
f.con <- rbind(aux, c(1,1), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(1,0))
f.dir <- c(rep("<=",946),">=",">", ">" )
f.rhs <- c(rep(1,946),0,0,0)
model <- lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, compute.sens = TRUE)
```

What I get is:

```
Success: the objective function is 0.753689
```

Which is the value of df$attempts[1]. Is there any other way to maximize this function or can you point out what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you`re trying to use a linear programming libary to solve a nonlinear problem. Try to reformulate the problem as presented in the documenatation. http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommended packages to do this for non-linear functions?